# matrix singular proof

Tags: linear-algebra

**Let A, B be n×n matrices. Show that if AB = A and B≠I then A must be singular.**

I was thikning to prove it by contradiction, showing if A is nonsingular then we have 
thta  AB=BA=A, therefore B is the inverse of A. Since B≠I then A need to be singular.

Is this proof complete and correct?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see how you went from $A$ being nonsingular and $AB=A$ to $AB=BA=A$ and then $B$ being the inverse of $A$.

Why not: if $A$ is nonsingular, then $AB=A$ implies $B=A^{-1}AB=A^{-1}A=I$, contradicting the premise that $B\neq I$.

Answer (score 2):

**This is a direct proof:** Assuming that $B\ne I$ then there is $x,y\in\Bbb R^n$ such that $\boxed{x\ne y}$ and $Bx=y$. Now we have

$$ABx=\boxed{Ay=Ax}\implies A\;\text{isn't injective}\iff A\;\text{isn't bijective}$$